# Which file should I keep: .io-config.json or ionic.config.json?

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2

I recently migrated my Ionic app into Ionic Cloud and after running `ionic io init` in the command-line, I noticed that I end up with two (config?) json files that seem to have the same purpose. However they have different names and I am not sure which one should be kept. The contents are as follows:

.io-config.json

```
{
 "app_id": "id",
 "api_key": "key"
}
```

ionic.config.json

```
{
 "name": "name",
 "app_id": "id",
 "watchPatterns": [
   "www/**/*",
   "!www/lib/**/*"
 ]
```

}

Which one should be kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an expert on Ionic's Slack, both files should be kept. They each have their own specific purpose.